# How to limit scope with dagger2 about ViewModelFactory?

Tags: android, dagger-2, android-viewmodel

I'm using Android Architecture Component with Dagger2 which recommended by Google. I followed the [Google Sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/GithubBrowserSample) but it is not perfect.

This solution does simplify injection, but if my ViewModels rely on the database, a Dao was needed when create the viewmodel. For now the factory was binded to the AppModule for providing global using. So ViewModel must be provided in AppModule to adding to the map. Thus the Dao alse be global.

Since Dao may only used in some special activity, creating him globally is a waste and inconvenient to manage.

I tried to move definition of bindViewModel function to ActivityModule but errors was given as follwed:

```
 [Dagger/MissingBinding] java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<? extends androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
public abstract interface AppComponent {
                ^
      java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<? extends androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>> is injected at
          com.chenhe.platform.viewmodel.MyViewModelFactory(creators)
      com.chenhe.platform.viewmodel.MyViewModelFactory is injected at
......
```

AppModule:

```
@Module(subcomponents = [LocalWatchFaceComponent::class], includes = [ViewModelModule::class])
class AppModule(private val context: Context) {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideContext(): Context = context

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideAppDataBase(): AppDatabase = AppDatabase.getInstance(context)

    // I want move code below to ActivityModule. But Dao was needed by viewmodel by factory map
    @Provides
    fun provideLocalWatchFaceDao(database: AppDatabase) = database.localWatchFaceDao()
}
```

ViewModel:

```
class LocalWatchFaceViewModel @Inject constructor(
        private val appCtx: Context,
        localWatchFaceRepository: LocalWatchFaceRepository) : ViewModel() {}
```

MapKey:

```
@MustBeDocumented
@Target(
        AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION,
        AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_GETTER,
        AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_SETTER
)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@MapKey
annotation class ViewModelKey(val value: KClass<out ViewModel>)
```

ViewModelModule:

```
@Module
abstract class ViewModelModule {
    @Binds
    abstract fun bindViewModelFactory(factory: MyViewModelFactory): ViewModelProvider.Factory

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(LocalWatchFaceViewModel::class)
    abstract fun bindLocalWatchFaceViewModel(viewModel: LocalWatchFaceViewModel): ViewModel
}
```

Factory:

```
@Singleton
class MyViewModelFactory @Inject constructor(
        private val creators: Map<Class<out ViewModel>, @JvmSuppressWildcards Provider<ViewModel>>
) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        val creator = creators[modelClass] ?: creators.entries.firstOrNull {
            modelClass.isAssignableFrom(it.key)
        }?.value ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("unknown model class $modelClass")
        try {
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            return creator.get() as T
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw RuntimeException(e)
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any plan to gracefully divide the scope?

Comment: I think the multi-binding approach is a mistake, I'd say prefer the approach outlined in https://youtu.be/9fn5s8_CYJI?t=1724

Comment: You should remove `@Singleton` from `MyViewModelFactory`. There's no need to scope this class as it doesn't maintain state.

Comment: @DavidMedenjak Oh yes, but the problem still there.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Awesome solution! In contrast, multi-binding is very ugly.